# Using Automapper to return IQueryable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, automapper, llblgenpro

I am trying to return an IQueryable object in one of my functions and using mapping (Automapper). It manage to return an IEnumerable object fine but as soon as i try to return an IQueryable object it throws me an error:

This is the error:

Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
LLBLGenProQuery`1 -> CostCentre
SD.LLBLGen.Pro.LinqSupportClasses.LLBLGenProQuery`1[[Mail.DAL.EntityClasses.TblCostCentreEntity, Mail.DAL, Version=1.0.4638.16064, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] -> Mail.Model.CostCentre

Destination path:
CostCentre

Source value:
SD.LLBLGen.Pro.LinqSupportClasses.LLBLGenProQuery`1[Mail.DAL.EntityClasses.TblCostCentreEntity]

This is the code:

Dim metaData As New LinqMetaData
        Dim q = From p In metaData.TblCostCentre _
                    Select p
        Mapper.CreateMap(Of TblCostCentreEntity, CostCentre)()

```
    Dim t As IEnumerable(Of CostCentre) = Mapper.Map(Of CostCentre)(q)
    'Select New CostCentre With {.Active = p.Active, .CostCentre = p.CostCentre, .CreatedBy = p.CreatedBy, .DateCreated = p.DateCreated, .DateLastModified = p.DateLastModified, .ModifiedBy = p.ModifiedBy, .CostCentreID = p.CostCentreId}

    Return t
```

Comment: Please refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212126/does-automapper-support-linq/12365931#12365931) for the proper solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for Automapper to actually perform the mapping, it has to see each element in the IQueryable. Once you've iterated over a queryable, it is no longer queryable as it has been queried already.

Comment: This link explains this further (only for llblgen users) - http://www.llblgen.com/tinyforum/Messages.aspx?ThreadID=17364

Comment: Incorrect: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12365931/178620 for the solution.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone that might miss [the comment link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212126/does-automapper-support-linq/12365931#12365931), you can use Automapper's `[QueryableExtensions][1]`, specifically `ProjectTo`. For example:

```cs
var collection = _db.Patients
     .ProjectTo<PatientDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider);
```

This will create an IQueryable projection from the db entity.