# Easy way to fill object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture, entity-framework-6

I have the following class:

```
    public class SectionViewModel
    {
        private static EFModels.VTSEntities _db = new EFModels.VTSEntities();
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string SectionName { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }
        public string SiteName { get; set; }
   }
```

I want to select one element from _db.Sections and fill object of this class. I can do it like it:

```
    public SectionViewModel(int ID)
    {
        var s = (from i in _db.Sections
                 where i.ID == ID
                 select new SectionViewModel()
                 {
                     ID = i.ID,
                     SectionName = i.SectionName,
                     Active = i.Active,
                     SiteName = i.Site.SiteName
                 }).FirstOrDefault();
        ID = s.ID;
        SectionName = s.SectionName;
        Active = s.Active;
    }
```

It works, but when count of fields is tens, code is huge. I would like to write something similar

```
    // IT DOES NOT WORK, ONLY EXAMPLE
    public SectionViewModel(int ID)
    {
        this = (from i in _db.Sections
                 where i.ID == ID
                 select new SectionViewModel()
                 {
                     ID = i.ID,
                     SectionName = i.SectionName,
                     Active = i.Active,
                     SiteName = i.Site.SiteName
                 }).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

ADDED:

Create SectionViewModel object (it's a View model class):

```
    public ActionResult SectionForm(int? id)
    {
        SectionViewModel model = new SectionViewModel(id);
        return View(model);
    }
```

but, of course, it's impossible because "this" is available only for read. Any way to do it?

Comment: @Gert Arnold, I have added

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, this is why products like [Automapper](http://automapper.org/) exist.

Comment: I'd recommend you read about how to work with MVC + EF. Your code is an dense collection of wrong patterns apparently inspired by faint echoes of past programming traditions. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: I have read tons of such articles. Could you describe why my approach is wrong? I just want to fill my View model in constructor if it's necessary. Which pattern is broken?

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**

OK, so you construct a `SectionViewModel`, not a `Section`, from a `Section`. That makes some difference, but still many remarks from my original answer apply.

A better way to do this is

```
public ActionResult SectionForm(int id)
{
    Section section = this._context.Sections.Find(id);
    SectionViewModel model = .... // Mapping code
    return View(model);
}
```

This part `// Mapping code` can be anything that copies properties from `section` to `model`. You could use AutoMapper.

The reason not to do this in `SectionViewModel`'s constructor is that there shouldn't be a static context there in the first place. You could create and dispose a context in stead. But who says that `SectionViewModel`s are always constructed individually? Maybe in another method you will return a list of them. Creating each model separately would be highly inefficient. [AutoMapper's `Project().To`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12365931/861716) approach would be appropriate there.

---

**Original text**

It's absurd to construct an object in a constructor (which is what happens by the part `var s = (...).FirstOrDefault()`) and then copy its properties to the owner of the constructor, which is the same type, `Section`. It's even more absurd that in the query you *also* construct a `Section` from a section. So after running the statement...

```
Section model = new Section(id);
```

...you have constructed three identical `Section`s of which the last one is finally used:

Section 1: `from i in _db.Sections where i.ID == ID select i`.
Section 2: `select new Section() {...}`
Section 3: `Section(int ID)`

And EF doesn't even allow a statement like

```
from i in _db.Sections
select new Section() {...}
```

It will tell you that you can't construct an entity in an LINQ-to-Entities query.

But removing this `select new Section() {...}` is not even the beginning of a sound refactoring. The whole construct is absurd.

Another bad practice is to have a static context. Contexts are designed to have a short lifespan, because they cache each entity they fetch from the database. A static context is a memory leak.

The way to achieve what you want is simply...

```
public ActionResult SectionForm(int id)
{
    Section model = this._context.Sections.Find(id);
    return View(model);
}
```

...where `this._context` is an instance of your `VTSEntities` that is created per controller instance (or injected into it by an Inversion of Control container).

Your programming style is faintly reminiscent of [*Active Record*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern), a pattern that doesn't mix well with EF's repository/unit of work pattern (where `DbSet` is a repo and a `DbContext` is a UoW). It also breaks the *persistance ignorance* principle that EF is built on. It breaks query composability and it easily causes `n + 1` queries.

Comment: My Section class is View Model class, not EF class! So, your example is not appropriate. I will remove Section class to SectionViewModel in my question for more clear!

Comment: and using EF model class for View is very bad approach (which I can see in your controller method). EF model is EF model, View model is View model!

Comment: Please see the revised answer.

Comment: if I would like from 2 or more entities (i.e. SectionViewModel is filled from Sections and one parameter from Sites), your approach is unappropriate

Comment: I just point a situation, why your approach can't be good. You propose to get an object of model class and then copy to object of view model class.

Comment: The point of this Q&A is the place where you construct view model. How and what to create is secondary. Of course you can project *any* query to *any* view model. You can project to view models *containing* view models, which is another reason not to do the query in a VM's own constructor.