# Cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6, automapper, anonymous-types

I want to make a projection as a performance wise but the select part returns an anonymous type and I can't to make required mapping.

```
 var jobDegreesQuery = _context.JOBDEGREEs.AsQueryable().Select(d=> new {d.DEGREE_CODE,d.DEGREE_NAME });

            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
                jobDegreesQuery = jobDegreesQuery.Where(c => c.DEGREE_NAME.Contains(name));

            var jobDegreeDTOs = jobDegreesQuery
               .ToList()
               .Select(Mapper.Map<JOBDEGREE, JobDegreeDTO>); //The error
```

---

> The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.Select(IEnumerable, Func)' cannot be
>   inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

How can I do the projection and map to `DTO` Successfully ?

Comment: You should use [`ProjectTo`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12365931/861716) here.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand you want to map JOBDEGREEs to JobDegreeDTO. You are first selecting it as anonymous type, so I think AutoMapper can not map because you are giving anon. type.

Change your code as below it will perform better:

```
IQueryable<JOBDEGREEs> jobDegreesQuery = _context.JOBDEGREEs; // it is already queryable

if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
    jobDegreesQuery = jobDegreesQuery.Where(c => c.DEGREE_NAME.Contains(name));

var jobDegreeDTOs = jobDegreesQuery
   //.Select(d=> new {d.DEGREE_CODE,d.DEGREE_NAME }) // do you need this?
   .Select(d => Mapper.Map<JOBDEGREE, JobDegreeDTO>(d)); // here you can give any expression
   .ToList()
```

Comment: I get the same compile error related to anonymous type.

Comment: As I understand you want to map JOBDEGREEs to JobDegreeDTO. You are first selecting it as anonymous type, so I think AutoMapper can not map because you are giving anon. type. What looks like your dto? What fields do you want to select? I edited my answer can you try again?

Comment: Do u mean that if my `DTO` consists of just `(DEGREE_CODE,DEGREE_NAME)` then last change did the required projection.

Comment: Yes, in the above code you can select it as dto manually or map it via second select statement. Is that solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

What is the result of your `ToList()`? It is a List of objects of some anonymous class, that contains data extracted from your sequence of `JobDegrees`

Whenever you want to use `Enumerable.Select` on a sequence of objects, you'll first have to name an identifier that represents one element of your sequence. This identifier is the part before the `=>`. After the `=>` you'll write the code to return one object using this input identifier.

This is a difficult way to say something like:

```
IEnumerable<Person> myPersons = ...
var firstNames = myPersns.Select(person => person.FirstName);
```

Here the `person` before the `=>` represents one item of your collection of `Persons`. Hence `person` seems a proper name for this identifier.

If you want you can use any identifier to identify a `person`, although not all identifiers will improve readability:

```
var firstNames = myPersns.Select(x => x.FirstName);
```

When using LINQ and entity framework it is good practice to identify collections with plural nouns and elements of collections with singular nouns.

After the `=>` you write some code that uses this input `person` to return exactly one object. In this example the `FirstName` of the `person`.

**Back to your question**

The result of your `ToList` is a sequence of objects with a `DegreeCode` and a `DegreeName`.

If you want to convert every object in your sequence into one other object (this is called projection), you'll have to identify one object of your sequence before the '=>'.

For example

```
...ToList()
.Select(extractedDegreeData => ...)
```

Here, every `extractedDegreeData` corresponds with one element of your list.

Now what do you want to do with one such `extractedDegreeData`? You want to return the return value of `Mapper.Map<JOBDEGREE, JobDegreeDTO>(extractedDegreeData)`.

Therefore your code should be like:

```
...ToList()
.Select(extractedDegreeData => Mapper.Map<JOBDEGREE, JobDegreeDTO>(extractedDegreeData));
```

### Advice:

While constructing your LINQ query, don't use functions like `ToList`, or any other functions that does not return `IEnumerable<TResult>`, it is a waste of processing power. What if after your `Select` you would have put `Take(2)`? What a waste to create the complete list of 1000 elements if you only wanted the first two!

Therefore functions like `ToList`, `FirstOrDefault`, `Max`, `Count` should always be the last in your linq query.

Finally: `dbContext.JobDegrees` is a `DbSet<JobDegree>`, which implements `IQueryable<JobDegree>`, hence there is no need to use `AsQueryable`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation but I get the following error:
`Argument 1: cannot convert from '<anonymous type: int DEGREE_CODE, string DEGREE_NAME>' to 'DomainClasses.JOBDEGREE'`

Comment: I don't know your `mapper.map` function. Check what it expects as input and provide the proper input