# Effect on AsNoTracking when mapping entities to DTO

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, ef-core-2.2

When mapping an EF result to DTO, adding AsNoTracking to EF query has any effect on performance?

Ex.

```
_context.Students.Where(x => x.age > 15).AsEnumerable().Select(x => ToDTO(x)).ToList();
```

Vs.

```
_context.Students.Where(x => x.age > 15).AsNoTracking().AsEnumerable().Select(x => ToDTO(x)).ToList();
```

Comment: I doubt is it even works - how EF will translate ToDTO to SQL? However, `AsNoTracking` will not have any effect, because you return DTO not actual context's class, EF can't track DTO.

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov: The problem here is AsEnumerable() method, which materializes entities, thus context will set up change tracking. That means unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Similar discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57233397/861716). You could mark you question as duplicate of that one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will have effect. So far the query is materialized via `AsEnumerable()` method and will set up change tracking for every single entity returned, thus there will be overhead.

In general, if you are querying data and using them just for read-only purposes it is reasonable to disable tracking.

[Tracking vs. No-Tracking Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking)